# « Bilingual » et « bilingue » — faux amis ou presque?

Tags: traduction, anglais, sens

À plusieurs reprises dans des conversations, j'ai eu l'impression que le « *bilingual* » anglais n'a pas tout à fait le même sens que le « bilingue » français.

Le sens de base est le même : « parle deux langues », mais il me semble qu'en anglais, on va seulement considérer quelqu'un comme bilingue s'il a deux langues maternelles, ou s'il s'approche de ce niveau de maîtrise dans les deux langues, tandis qu'en français, il n'y a pas ce sens restrictif.

En conséquence, j'ai l'impression que je pourrais dire à un français que je suis bilingue, mais ne pas dire que je suis « *bilingual* » à un anglais.

Est-ce que j'ai répondu à ma propre question, ou y a-t-il d'autres subtilités ?

Answer (score 12):

- Pour ce qui est du français, effectivement. Quelqu'un qui maîtrise parfaitement une autre langue que sa langue maternelle peut se dire *bilingue*. 
  Trop souvent, cependant, *bilingue* est utilisé en lieu et place de *avancé* (voire *(tout à fait) à l'aise*), qui signifie que sans être *bilingue* la personne peut sans difficulté travailler, conduire des réunions, ou discuter de sujets variés dans la langue sans que sa compréhension ni l'expression de ses propres idées en soit modifiées.
  En fait, en français, *bilingue* implique souvent de vivre ou d'avoir vécu dans un pays où se parle la langue concernée car en plus de la maîtrise de la grammaire et du vocabulaire s'ajoutent les expressions, la capacité de jouer sur les mots ou de jouer des niveaux de langage. D'une façon générale, de maîtriser la fraction du langage qui ne trouve pas d'explications dans les livres.
- Pour ce qui est de l'usage anglais de cette expression, je ne suis pas certain. Je pense que l'on utiliserait plus volontiers *fluent* que *bilingual* pour signifier ce qui est décrit plus haut, mais c'est à confirmer.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec le sens que tu donnes à *bilingue*, et je pense que *bilingual* a exactement le même sens (et les deux mots sont donc des vrais amis).

Comment: Je pense que les deux mots sont à l'origine strictement identiques, et qu'il s'agit plus d'une différence culturelle et un usage abusif qui a petit-à-petit amoindri le sens français. (NB: "fluent" se voudrait la traduction de "courant").